# Loading a nav bar when in a specific controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, renderpartial

I am having a bit of trouble in rails.

What I want to do is to display some extra links in the application layout when a specific controller is in use. How do I do this?

I am loading the pages dynamically using jquery and I tried using <%if controller_name == "foo"%> then do some magic, without any success.

If somebody could point me in the right direction or even a jquery-rails rendering tutorial that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: When are you expecting those links to show up? or what event should trigger the links to show?

Comment: I was hoping to accomplish something like this , in application.html.erb: <% if foo controller %> <ul><li>blah</li></ul> <%end%>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the content_for magic provided by Rails. It allows you to specify something like this in your application layout:

```
<%= yield :header %>
```

And then in your individual templates do something like this:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  Content I want put in the header
<% end %>
```

Which basically results in the content inside the content_for block being captured and rendered at the point of the yield statement. So, you can specify that in the templates for your controller.

Comment: Right on the money, Thank you so much.